# Upload to OneDrive with Service Principal

Tags: azure, automation, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I need to create a service principal that has permissions to upload to a **specific** OneDrive folder. What inputs should I be providing when creating a Service Principal with either the bash CLI or PowerShell with this kind of scope.

Or is my approach wrong - maybe I should be using the OneDrive UI to "share" a folder with a Service Principal or Active Directory application?

Comment: There is just a way to set for all files, not for `specific`.